# Why doesn't `instanceof car` work if `typeof car` does? Is there any way of finding the type of the class?

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I know it's possible to do the following:

```
car instanceof Car; // true
typeof car; // 'object'
```

But what if didn't already know `Car`? How would I figure out the class type of an instance?

Comment: car.constructor.name

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(car).constructor`

Comment: @xianshenglu `Object.getPrototypeOf(car).constructor.name`

Comment: So it's actually the same as @ippi specified above.

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf` is safer, as *technically*, you can override the `constructor` of the instance. Shouldn't happen often but I'd go for `Object.getPrototypeOf` as it's clearer.